# Build Mongo Query based on query parameters in url

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to build a query as per the value available in the query parameters of the URL. The sample URL is    :-

```
http://localhost:3000/api/user?page=&status=&search&role_id=
```

So when the **status** is available, the **where clause related to it should work**, the **same for search and role_id**.

I have tried to built a query where pagination part along with search parameter is working perfectly. But when I pass/set the keys of
query string, the query shows no results.

The query I have build so far is something like this:-

```
let {page, search, status, role_id} = req.query;
role_id = role_id ? role_id : null;
status = status ? status : null;
const currentPage = parseInt(page) || 1;
const perPage = recordsPerPage;
const userData = await User.find({
                                $and: [
                                    {
                                        $or : [
                                                {username:{'$regex' : search, '$options' : 'i'}},
                                                {email:{'$regex' : search, '$options' : 'i'}}
                                            ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        $or : [
                                            {status : status}
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                            $or : [
                                                {role_id : role_id}
                                            ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        email: { $ne: 'xxxxx@gmail.com' }
                                    }
                                ]
                            })
                            .sort({_id : -1})
                            .populate('role_id')
                            .skip((currentPage - 1) * perPage).limit(perPage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to rely on `$or` and `$and` in your query, you can just conditionally add fields to your query. A mongoose query is just passed an object and can be built outside the function call.

This way you won't have to worry about edge cases such as a user with status `null` being returned whenever you leave out the status field from your query.

```
let {page, search, status, role_id} = req.query;
role_id = role_id ? role_id : null;
status = status ? status : null;
const currentPage = parseInt(page) || 1;
const perPage = recordsPerPage;
const query ={
    email: { $ne: 'xxxxx@gmail.com' }
}
if (status) {
    query.status = status
}
if (role_id) {
    query.role_id = role_id
}
if (search) {
    query.username = {'$regex' : search, '$options' : 'i'}
    delete query.email
    query['$and'] = [
        { email: {'$regex' : search, '$options' : 'i'}},
        { email: { $ne: 'xxxxx@gmail.com' } }
    ]
}
const userData = await User.find(query)
    .sort({_id : -1})
    .populate('role_id')
    .skip((currentPage - 1) * perPage).limit(perPage);
```

As an aside, I think a query with a `$regex` and a `$ne` on the same field (`email` in your example) may be very slow once executed on a large collection.

Comment: okay, I will try this out. As for your side note, the query will only work on 10 collections at a time as it is combined with pagination. Also, if you don't mind, would you let me know what the following block is doing:-
**delete query.email**

Comment: Just a small update to your code:-
```
query['$and'] = [
                { email: {'$regex' : search, '$options' : 'i'}},
                { email: { $ne: 'xxxxx@gmail.com' } }
            ]
```

Comment: @Varun.Kumar Thanks, I applied the edit. I delete the default email not equal to part of the query, as I then add it back with the regex in the `$and` query. This may not be needed - I don't know what would happen if email field is in the query multiple times. You can try both versions, and use mongo's `explain` to see how the query is executed